# Where to Set system property 'org.apache.logging.log4j.simplelog.StatusLogger.level' to TRACE to show Log4j2 internal initialization logging

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I need help on this matter. I am not sure where to set system property and what is the syntax.
Is that hibernate.cfg.xml or hibernate.hbm.xml or pom.xml?

Comment: How do you launch your app?

Comment: I am using eclipse with javee/hibernate in tomcat server with window 10, Is that your question?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can enable log4j2 internal status logging by setting system property in this way:

```
java -Dorg.apache.logging.log4j.simplelog.StatusLogger.level=TRACE yourApp
```

2. In Servers tab, double click on tomcat server -> click on open launch configuration -> click on (x)=Arguments

In VMarguments add the following:

```
-Dorg.apache.logging.log4j.simplelog.StatusLogger.level=TRACE
```

See also [this section](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#How_do_I_debug_my_configuration.3F) of the documentation.

Comment: Hello SternK :Thank you but I am not sure is that I need to run on command prompt. When I did, I got this message: Error: Could not find or load main class yourApp
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: yourApp

Comment: I mean under `yourApp` - YourAppClassName that have `public static main(String[] args)` method

Comment: I have servlet InitHibernate and file structure like this

Comment: Sorry could copy and paste the snapshop but there is no static main for lunch but just servlet

Comment: Thank you SternK now no more statuslogger error is gone!

Comment: Hello Mr SternK : Now I get this error and wonder if you can help me: ERROR StatusLogger Catching
 java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "shutdownHooks")

Comment: I got this log4j2 error again: at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.initializeShutdownCallbackRegistry(Log4jContextFactory.java:125)
 at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.<init>(Log4jContextFactory.java:92)
 at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.<init>(Log4jContextFactory.java:58) I was able to run this program!!